# Hypothetical: can taxes ever cause a net loss on otherwise-profitable stocks?

Tags: united-states, calculation, capital-gains-tax

Let's imagine a hypothetical situation:

- I start with $100, and buy 10 shares of a company at $10 each. The next day I sell the 10 shares at $12 each.
- A week later, the price drops back to $10 and this time I buy 12 shares (using the $20 profit from the last sale).
- The stock then goes back to $12 and I sell all 12 shares. I now have $144.
- The stock drops back to $10 and I buy 14 shares this time (with $4 left over). Then I sell at $12 again. I now have $168 + $4 = $172.

In the US, how do taxes work here? Let's say I'm in a 25% tax bracket. Do I pay $5 tax for the first sale, plus $6 for the second sale, plus $6 for the third sale, totaling $16 in tax? Or do I pay ($172-$100=$72)*.25=$18 in taxes?

What if I then take that $172 and buy 17 shares again at $10 (with $2 left over), but this time it drops and I sell at $6, so I'm left with $102 + $2 left over. Am I still on the hook for the earlier $16 or $18 in taxes? Or can I write off all of the losses and end up paying just ($104-$100)*.25=$1 in tax? Does it make a difference if the profit is December 31 and the loss is on January 1?

Aside from it being impossible to predict the market, is there anything else to be aware of if I just repeatedly buy low and sell high, taking advantage of short-term fluctuations in the market? Let's imagine I'm not doing any margin trading; this is purely cash.

Comment: It probably depends on how hypothetical you want to get. If there was a per-transaction tax, then yeah, you could get a net loss. Indeed, the very rationale behind introducing such taxes is to prevent people from speculating on short-term fluctuations (and limit the supposedly associated volatility of the market and/or unearned gain).

Comment: Your arithmetic seems to be wrong in the first half of your question.  The tax is the same whether you do it transaction by transaction or in net.  In the first case it's (.25 x $20) + (.25 x $24) + (.25 * $28) = $5 + $6 + $7 = $18.  That's the same as you computed for .25 x $72.

Comment: "Nobody ever went broke making a profit" ?  Unless your marginal tax rate exceeds 100%, I can't imagine it happening.

Comment: There are a couple of discontinuities in US taxes where a marginal dollar income can cost more than one dollar of net taxes.  Are you eligible for EITC?

Answer (score 4):

You have a sequence of questions here, so a sequence of answers:

If you stopped at the point where you had multiple wins with a net profit of $72, then you would pay regular income tax on that $72. It's a short term capital gain, which does not get special tax treatment, and the fact that you made it on multiple transactions does not matter.

When you enter your next transaction that takes the hypothetical loss the question gets more complicated.

- If everything happened in the same tax year, then you'll be taxed on the gain net of all of the transactions.  In your example, that means a net gain of $4.
- If you take the loss in the next calendar year, then you pay tax on the $72 the first year, and you can deduct the loss in the second year against other gains that you have that year.  If you have no other gains in the second year, you can roll some amount of loss forward to future years.

In either case, you are paying a percentage on net gains.  If you took a two year view in the second case and you don't have anything to offset your loss in the second year, then I guess you could say that you paid more tax than you won in the total sequence of trades over the two years.

Although you picked a sequence of trades where it does not appear to play, if you're going to pursue this type of strategy then you are likely at some point to run into a case where the "wash sale" rules apply, so you should be aware of that.  You can find information on this elsewhere on this site and also, for example, here: http://www.marketwatch.com/story/understanding-the-wash-sale-rules-2015-03-02  Basically these rules require you to defer recording a loss under some circumstances where you have rapid wins and losses on "substantially identical" securities.

**EDIT**
A slight correction, you can take part of your losses in the second year even if you have no off-setting gain.  From the IRS:

> If your capital losses exceed your capital gains, the amount of the excess loss that you can claim on line 13 of Form 1040 to lower your income is the lesser of $3,000, ($1,500 if you are married filing separately)

Comment: I guess carrying forward losses isn't of any use if you don't have any subsequent gains... (for instance, if you lost $72 the first year, $144 the second year, and $350 the third year, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The original post's $16 has two errors:

- $5 + $6 + $6 = $17, not $16
- The tax on the final gain is $7, not $6.

Here is the first scenario:

`.                                                 Tax Liability($) on   Net
.                        Cash    # of     Price    Paper     Realized   Value
Time:                     ($)    Shares   ($/sh)   Profits    Profits    ($)
1. Start with:            100        -      n/a         -          -      100
2. After buy  10@10$/sh:    -       10       10         -          -      100
3. Before selling:          -       10       12        (5)         -      115
4. After sell 10@12$/sh:  120        -      n/a         -         (5)     115
5. After buy  12@10$/sh:    -       12       10         -         (5)     115
6. Before selling:          -       12       12        (6)        (5)     133
7. After sell 12@12$/sh:  144        -      n/a         -        (11)     133
8. After buy  14@10$/sh:    4       14       10         -        (11)     133
9. Before selling:          4       14       12        (7)       (11)     154
10.After sell 14@12$/sh:  172        -      n/a         -        (18)     154`

At this point, assuming that all of the transactions occurred in the same fiscal year, and the realized profits were subject to a 25% short-term capital gains tax, you would owe $18 in taxes.  Yes, this is 25% of $172 - $100.

Answer (score -4):

This was the day traders dilemma. You can, on paper, make money doing such trades. But because you do not hold the security for at least a year, the earnings are subject to short term capital gains tax unless these trades are done inside a sheltered account like a traditional IRA.

There are other considerations as well: wash sale rules and number of days to settle.

In short, the glory days of rags to riches by day trading are long gone, if they were ever here in the first place.

Edit: the site will not allow me to add a comment, so I am putting my response here:

Possibly, yes. One big 'gotcha' is that your broker reports the proceeds from your sales, but does not report your outflows from your buys. Then there is the risk you take by the broker refusing to sell the security until the transaction settles. Not to mention wash sale rules. You are trying to win at the 'buy low, sell high' game. But you have a 25% chance, at best, of winning at that game. Can you pick the low? Maybe, but you have a 50% chance of being right. Then you have to pick the high. And again you have a 50% chance of doing that. 50% times 50% is 25%. Warren Buffet did not get rich that way. Buffet buys and holds. Don't be a speculator, be a 'buy and hold' investor. Buy securities, inside a sheltered account like a traditional IRA, that pay dividends then reinvest those dividends into the security you bought. Scottrade has a Flexible Reinvestment Program that lets you do this with no commission fees.

Comment: But. Can the tax ever exceed the profit? That was the question.

Comment: Where you get that you have a 50% chance picking the high and 50% chance of picking the low?

Comment: If you buy at a price then the price could go up from where you bought it or it could go down from where you bought it, thus you have a 50% chance of picking the bottom. If you sell at a price then the price could go down or the price could go up thus you have a 50% chance at picking the top. This is simple math taught in elementary school. So 50% times 50% is 25%, you have, at best, a 25% chance of picking both the bottom and the top of a trading range.